# UICollectionView : Support for reordering on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uicollectionview, ios9

So I'm dealing with UICollectionView reordering in my Swift App. I discovered the new iOS9 functions that does the work quite well.

I realized that it has to run on an >= iOS9 device, and my App has to be compatible with iOS8.

Does anyone knows what should I use in replacement of those ?

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public func beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool // returns NO if reordering was prevented from beginning - otherwise YES
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public func updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(targetPosition: CGPoint)
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public func endInteractiveMovement()
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public func cancelInteractiveMovement()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout for reordering collection views in pre iOS 9 apps. Works pretty good.

[LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout)

Just need to implement a few delegate calls and use it as your collection view layout.